# How to remove /tmp/ partition and keep it in RAM?

Tags: ram, tmp

I made a /tmp parition alongside partitions for / /home /root /var and /boot. It was a mistake to make a partition to tmp/. Is there a way for tmp/ to use RAM instead of the designated space I made on the SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/etc/fstab` comment out any line that might mount your separate /tmp partition on your hard drive. You then can have `/tmp` in RAM with the following line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime 0       0
```

After this, you can remove the dedicated /tmp partition on your drive using a partition editor or use it for something else.

Comment: Thanks this worked.